How do I grant permissions to a local Windows group to work with an elevated process?
Is there a way to grant read/write/execution permissions to a local Windows group with PowerShell, enabling non-admin users to interact with a single elevated process?
For instance, Docker Desktop utilizes the SYSTEM service com.docker.service.exe and automatically grants elevated rights to members of the local Windows group docker-users. This allows non-admin users to launch Docker Desktop without needing elevated permissions.

It doesn't seem that Docker Desktop directly works with the Docker service process – it works with a pipe or some other communication object that the Docker service creates. Both a process and a pipe can have access lists attached, but they're still two separate objects (with independent access) and you won't go far trying to open up one when the program needs the other.

That’s true but this named pipe is protected and only users of docker-users can interact with this pipe. Moreover, docker desktops has outsourced all privileged operations to this process and only users of docker-users can work with this process

Right, but it's still the pipe, not the process itself, that you need to change the protection of.
